# Smali iterating over Arraylist

Tags: java, android, logging, smali

im trying to translate this java line to smali code

```
v1 = "tag"
p0 = Arraylist

p0.forEach(x -> Log.d(v1,x));
```

this is what i have come up with

```
const-string/jumbo v4, "tag"

invoke-virtual {p0}, Ljava/util/Collection;->iterator()Ljava/util/Iterator;

move-result-object v1

:goto_4

invoke-interface {v1}, Ljava/util/Iterator;->hasNext()Z

move-result v2

if-eqz v2, :cond_16

invoke-interface {v2}, Ljava/util/Iterator;->next()Ljava/lang/Object;

move-result-object v0

check-cast v0, Ljava/lang/String;

invoke-static {v4, v0}, Landroid/util/Log;->d(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

goto :goto_4

:cond_16
```

The App runs without crashing but the log entries are not generated

Edit: i leave this here because i think it would work and could be useful , i solved the problem by converting to String and cutting the string with a for-loop , i suspect the iterator is buggy

also thx to jesusfreke himself for looking over the code

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with the smali. Does the app launch? Are you sure your injected code is even getting run?

Comment: on api 21 it crashes with "failed compile-time verification" but i read that this can be fixed with an higher api and on api 25 the app runs and the code runs at least to above setting up the iterator

Comment: What errors do you see on api 21?

Comment: it crashes with the error ~ verfier couldn't verify because is failed compile time verification but it crashes like also with for loops on api 21 and i read on here that this can be fixed by threading or moving up in api. Is there a guide for threading in smali because i need to do it anyway now because of WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window

Comment: You need to find out why it's failing verification. Look back further in the logs, probably around the time you installed the apk. There should be some logs from ART saying exactly why the verification is failing.

Comment: also, I have no idea why you think threading would solve your issue. if your dex file is failing verification, it means there is something wrong with the bytecode that you generated. You need to figure out what is wrong and fix it. Trying to use threads (???) or switch api levels almost certainly isn't going to help anything.